# A Question About Inheritance In My Game

Tags: c++, inheritance, sfml

I have a Player class that derives from Humanoid and Humanoid derives from Sprite like so

```
Sprite -> Humanoid -> Player
```

So far so good. Sprite has the virtual method

```
virtual sf::Sprite getSprite() { return sprite_; }
```

where sprite is an image object that can be drawn onto the screen.

Humanoid declares `virtual sf::Sprite getSprite();`

Player defines `virtual sf::Sprite getSprite() { return sprite_; }`

Sprite has a member `sprite_`; this is what I want to do:

1) Create a player class while passing a sprite like so

```
Player::Player(sf::Image image)
    : Humanoid()
{   
    sprite_.SetImage(image); // Converts sf::Image to sf::Sprite
}
```

2) Drawing it on the screen from my Game class like so

```
sf::Image playerImage;
if(!playerImage.LoadFromFile("Link/Link.png"))
    std::cin.get();

Player *player = new Player(playerImage);

/* ... */

App.Draw(player->GetSprite());
```

Testing the program, I have found that the `player->getSprite()` method is indeed called, but I fear that I may have hidden the `Sprite::getSprite()` method instead of actually deriving and using it. Since the Sprite class has a protected sprite_ member, I'm confused as to which sprite_ object I'm actually returning when I call the function.

Also, it seems like the image file got lost somewhere along the line, and before I post in the SFML forum I would like some confirmation as to whether or not my inheritance tree is actually correct or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `Sprite` class has a `sprite_` member and none of the derived classes (`Humanoid/Player`) have added a member with the same name then there is only one `sprite_` object for each instance and the function should work as expected. I don't understand why you're overriding `getSprite` if you give it the exact same behaviour though.

Comment: Probably because I don't understand inheritance enough. Do I have to write the declaration or definition if I wish to use a virtual function from a base class? Does it suffice to declare the function, or can I just leave it away if I'm using it unmodified?

Comment: @SoulBeaver, if you only want to use the virtual function you don't have to declare it at all, it's defined in the base class and you can access it (assuming it's not `private`). You only want to declare and define it if you're changing the behaviour.

Comment: or if it's a pure virtual. :)